# 表示名としてカタカナ名を書く

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求, 完了

私はカタカナで私の名前を書いています：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー：

> おっと!プロフィールの更新中に問題が発生しました。
>
> - 表示名には、英字、数字、スペース、アポストロフィ、またはハイフンのみを含めることができ、英字または数字から開始する必要があります。

編集：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 確かに[ひらがな](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12203)か[カタカナ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2988)か[漢字](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/369/)で始まるのはできるはず…もしかして原因は「・」なのか？

Comment: ❌「トーマス　エドワーズ」⭕️「トーマス エドワーズ」全角スペースは書き込めません。両方を使う「トーマス　 エドワーズ」

Comment: バグ扱いにしても良いかなと思いましたが、エラーメッセージの原文だと「英字」は「letters」と[なっている](https://ja.traducir.win/string/5445)のでひらがな・カタカナは含められるはずです。やはり「・」や「　」が弾かれているのだと思います。「・」「　」などが含められないのは不自然なので、機能の要求として扱えるかなと思います。含めた方が自然な文字は他にあるでしょうか？　「＝」など……？

Comment: 少し試してみたところ、現在でも、連続した全角スペースは許可されます (例: `山田　　太郎`) が、単一の全角スペース (例: `山田　太郎`) の場合、エラーが発生します。全角スペースを連続させる名前はあまりありませんが、単一の全角スペースを用いる名前は多いはずなので、不便かもしれません。(半角スペースはどちらでもエラーが発生しませんでした)

Comment: 全角スペースと中黒を追加して欲しいという内容をMeta Stack Exchangeに投稿してみました https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342382/341401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

挙動が変更され、全角スペース、および中黒が名前に使えるようになりました。

あわせてエラーメッセージの翻訳も変更しましたので、そのうちより自然なエラーになるはずです。

詳細: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342979/341401

Comment: ありがとうございました。私の名前のドット！